# Cascade Update Columns Relational Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, traits, relation

I'm trying to have a new trait or etc for my models

I have some relation in my database mysql and I'm using laravel 5.6

I have some tables include 'is_approved' column

now I want to create something that when I set is_approved to false for one of my table, all other tables that have relation with that table, updated to the value that I would choose.

how can I do that?

for example:

I have these tables:

```
-product_type [columns: 'id', 'type_name', 'is_approved']
-product_brand [columns: 'id', 'type_id', 'brand_name', 'is_approved']
-product_model [columns: 'id', 'brand_id', 'model_name', 'is_approved']
-product_name [columns: 'id', 'model_id', 'product_name', 'is_approved']
```

and all of these tables have the 'is_approved' column

I want, when I set one of product_type record 'is_approved' column to false all I relation records updated to false

Comment: Could you explain the relations between them?

Comment: @ka_lin I explained it well, but yeah of course. there's type_id in product_brand that refer to the relation between product_type and product_brand and the others are like this

Comment: What models have you defined?

Comment: @DelenaMalan ProductType, ProductBrand, ProductModel, ProductName :-??

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#events) on your models.

Answer (score 0):

To update column to other tables. You need to make it manually with respect of type_id. like this:

```
$productbrand = ProductBrand::where('type_id', $type_id)->update(['is_approved' => 1]);
$productmodel = ProductModel::where('brand_id', $productbrand->id)->update(['is_approved' => 1]);
$productname = ProductName::where('model_id', $productmodel->id)->update(['is_approved' => 1]);
```

or you can do this using trigger. for more details read this.

http://www.expertphp.in/article/laravel-53-creating-mysql-triggers-from-migration-with-example

Answer (score 0):

You can make `is_approved` column as part of all foreign keys with ON UPDATE CASCADE attribute:

```sql
create table product_type(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    type_name varchar(50),
    is_approved tinyint,
    index(id, is_approved)
);

create table product_brand (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    type_id int,
    brand_name varchar(50),
    is_approved tinyint,
    index(id, is_approved),
    foreign key (type_id, is_approved)
        references product_type(id, is_approved)
        on update cascade
);

create table product_model (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    brand_id int,
    model_name varchar(50),
    is_approved  tinyint,
    index(id, is_approved),
    foreign key (brand_id, is_approved)
        references product_brand(id, is_approved)
        on update cascade
);

create table product_name (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    model_id int,
    product_name varchar(50),
    is_approved  tinyint,
    foreign key (model_id, is_approved)
        references product_model(id, is_approved)
        on update cascade
);
```

[Online demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7Wk5HDM61t9xswPiRTjGBa/0)

A change in `product_type` will automaticly change the corresponding rows in `product_brand`.
A change in `product_brand` will cause a change in `product_model`.
A change in `product_model` will cause a change in `product_name`.